# How do I rename a field for an existing content entity type?

Tags: 8, entities

I created a content type, and I used it.

```
/**
 * @ContentEntityType(
 *   id = "program_permission",
 *   label = @Translation("Program permissions storage"),
 *   base_table = "program_permissions",
 *   admin_permission = "administer site configuration",
 *   entity_keys = {
 *      "id" = "id",
 *   },
 * )
 */
class ProgramPermission extends ContentEntityBase implements ProgramPermissionInterface
{

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function baseFieldDefinitions(EntityTypeInterface $entity_type)
  {
    $fields['id'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('integer')
      ->setLabel(t('ID'))
      ->setDescription(t('The ID of the entity.'))
      ->setReadOnly(TRUE);

    $fields['download'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('string')
      ->setLabel(t('Download'))
      ->setDescription(t('Download operation.'))
      ->setRequired(TRUE)
      ->setSettings(array(
        'type' => 'varchar_ascii',
        'max_length' => 1,
        'default' => self::TYPE_OPEN,
      ));
```

I need to rename the *download* field to *program_download*. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can't change an existing field's machine name once it has been created.

Comment: I doubt that it is impossible.

Comment: Even if it's possible, it's not good practice because if you have a View with field `download` it won't know that it got renamed to `program_download` and you're going to endup with a broken View field. Same thing if you already have custom template/twig/modules/php files that are utilizing the existing machine name.

Comment: may be exists some magic that will find in db all dependents and do update except php-files.

Comment: I suppose, but personally I wouldn't lose sleep over a machine name. But if you want to, I won't stop you.

Comment: I think i will create new clone with new name and copy values through db connection. and then will remove old.

Comment: This may have already been answered here: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/250937

Comment: You'll need to uninstall the current field, and then create the new field. You cannot change machine names, doing so would create fatal errors further down the line.