# How to duplicate/clone a field in a content type

Tags: media, 9

I have a custom content type with an image field. I want to convert this image field into media type. There are already thousands of nodes created with this content type.

One of the ways I've identified is to use the image field to media module. However this creates a clone of the image field. All the twig files and db instances will continue to use the image field.

What I'm trying to do now is to create a clone of the image field as image. Delete the original image field. use image field to media module on the second image field and set the machine name of the cloned media field to the original field's machine name. Does anybody have any suggestions on how I can go about this? I'm using drupal 9.

Comment: https://chromatichq.com/insights/migrating-drupal-file-fields-media-entities-without-migrate-module/  <-- here you go

Comment: For content types in general, a useful reference is [renaming a field](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/250927/how-do-i-rename-a-field).  You won't be renaming it-- you're changing the type-- but the approach is the same.